# how to stop the infinite loop and allow to accept the touches during this loop

Tags: objective-c

```
 while (true)
 {
    endtime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    double difftime = endtime - starttime;
    NSLog(@"The tine difference = %f",difftime);
    if (difftime >= 10)
    {
        NSURL *url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/a0.wav" , [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
        NSError *error;
        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
        [audioPlayer play];
        starttime = endtime;
    }

}
```

when i call this method my application enters in an infinite loop and doesnot accept any touches again how can solve this please?

Comment: "my application enters in an infinite loop" - because you told it to do so (what do you think `while(true)` does?)

Comment: Also, `difftime` is the name of a standard C function. Don't use it as a variable name. Furthermore, `+ [NSString stringWithFormat:]` is not suited for creating path names. `- [NSString stringByAppendingPathComponent:]` is, but in your specific case, you should just be using `- [NSBundle pathForResource:ofType:]` anyway.

Comment: For several reasons, this code doesn't make sense. Worse, it hogs the CPU (and drains battery). What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps, an asynchronous approach can solve this problem.

Comment: i know that but i need also inside this loop to takes all the touches will be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want it to play a sound every 10 seconds. You would be better using a timer like this...

```
NSTimer *yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(repeatedAction)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Then have your repeating function...

```
- (void)repeatedAction
{
    // do your stuff in here
}
```

The UI will be responsive all the time and you can have a cancel button with an action like this...

```
- (void)cancelRepeatedAction
{
    [self.yourTimer invalidateTimer];
}
```

This will stop the time rand the repeated action.

**HOWEVER**

You are also trying to download a file EVERY time you run your action.

A better approach would be to download the file once and store it.

Even better would be to download the file asynchronously.

Comment: i dont want to add a cancel button the job of the cancel button i want to accomplish it upon touchbegin

Comment: Well, run the `cancelRepeatedAction` method from touchBegin then. It doesn't change the method or the implementation. It works whether it's a button, a touch, a gesture etc... The thing to take from the answer though is use a timer not a loop.

Comment: You'll need to create the property for the timer and set the property when you're creating the timer in the first part. i.e. `self.yourTimer = [NSTimer blah...`

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you structure an event-driven application.  You are blocking the event processing queue (`NSRunLoop`) by not returning out of this function. So no touch events will get a chance to be processed until you return from this loop.

You need to play the sounds asynchronously - which `AVAudioPlayer` can do for you. Read up on the ADC documentation about queueing and playing music in AVFoundation.

For a start, you don't need the `while` loop at all. Just start the playback, and register for notifications of playback progress.  Make the `_audioPlayer` an ivar of your controller class, as its lifetime persists beyond the method used to load the file and initiate playback:

```
NSURL *url= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/a0.wav" , [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
NSError *error;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
_audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
[_audioPlayer play];
```

Then define a delegate method which implements the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` protocol, and provide at least this method:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
}
```

You can also provide a touch event handler in your view, which calls a `pauseAudio:` method in the controller class, which then calls:

```
[audioPlayer pause];
```

Have a good read through the docs, and study the sample code:

- [iOS Developer Library - ADC AVAudioPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Have a look at how this app is structured, with a controller registering for notifications and using a delegate for callbacks. It also uses a timer and features GUI updates.

- [iOS Developer Library - avTouch - media player sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/avTouch/Introduction/Intro.html)